# Unable to connect to wifi--does nothing

Tags: networking, wifi

I just purchased a pi 2 through the CanaKit, and I'm having some issues getting the wifi dongle to work.  It scans for networks and finds mine, but when I put in the passcode and click "OK," absolutely nothing happens.  It never connects to the network, and it never shows anything that suggests that it's attempting a connection, as I expect it would do.  I hooked it to an ethernet cable and did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to make sure everything was up to date, and I verified that the network configuration in `/etc/(something)/wpa_supplicant` is correct, though still no joy.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?  Anyone have an idea as to how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: Please use 'lsusb' (if not available use 'apt-get install usbutils') and post the device/dongle name and description.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just solved this issue.  Apparently for WEP networks, you have to remove the quotes from the key in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (I think that's it, don't have convenient access to my pi right now).  Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: It's great that you want to help, but your answer looks misleading to me. According to the official [examples](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf), WEP keys should work with or without quotes. Your issue was probably solved by something else.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **wpagui** and then use the GUI to setup WiFi network connection:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wpagui -y
```